# Assigning the value of a gcloud call to a GitHub actions variable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, github-actions, google-cloud-pubsub, cicd

Objective: To grab the `JOB_ID` of a unknown running pipeline using gcloud and assign it to a variable to use later for when I drain the pipeline.
`run: 'gcloud dataflow jobs list --region us-central1 --status active  --filter DataflowToBigtable --format="value(JOB_ID.scope()):"'`.
-- this will output something like : DataflowToBigtable0283384848 which is the JOB_ID I want to use.  I don't know this value at start and can't assign it from secret.  So if my action looks like this....

```
name: PI-Engine-Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches: [ develop, feature/deployment-workflow ]

env:
  BUCKET_NAME: ret-dev-dataflow
  PROJECT_ID: ret-01-dev
  REGION: us-central1
  PUBSUB_ID: steps.pubsub.outputs.JOB_ID. // I want to assign value here.

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'adopt'

    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml

    - name: Set up Cloud SDK
      uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
      with:
        project_id: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}
        service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }}
        export_default_credentials: true

    - name: Use gcloud CLI
      run: gcloud info
    - name: Install Maven
      run: mvn install
      ##  Gets the id for pubsub pipeline
    - name: Get the targeted pipelines
      id: pubsub
      run: 'gcloud dataflow jobs list --region us-central1 --status active  --filter DataflowToBigtable --format="value(JOB_ID.scope())"'
   - name: Drain Pubsub
    run: 'gcloud dataflow jobs drain ${{ PUBSUB_ID }}' ## I want to use the assingned value here.
```

Comment: Could you advise what exactly you want to achieve? Does your method works? Are you using some automatization?